# Change "Search and Filter" Plugin Default Text

Tags: html, css, wordpress, plugins

I've installed the free version of "Search and Filter" plugin. I want to change the default text on the dropdown menu "All Categories" and "All Tags" to something else. I've tried using CSS but it didn't work. How can I do this?

Comment: You can find the plugincode if you go to the websitefiles on the server. Go to the folder where your WP site is located and then wp-content/plugins . You should see the plugin there. Just keep in mind it is NOT a good idea to edit plugins directly since the next time you update you'll lose your changes. Its better to hook onto it/rewrite or maybe with js?. But since I don't know the code I cannot answer how to do that. Maybe you can update your question with some code if you found it :)

Comment: If you have full access to the admin dashboard navigate to plugins > plugin editor, there you can see and edit(It's a bad idea to edit a live plugin because the next update will delete all your changes) the plugin of you choice.

Answer (score 0):

If you have server FTP details then go to wp-content/plugins/your-plugin-folder, Try to find function where text like "All Categories" and "All Tags". Then try to call hook function using that function name from your wp-content/themes/your-theme/function.php.

So, when you update that plugin its not replace code on hook function and its working as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
[searchandfilter fields="search,product_tag,product_cat" submit_label ="Search" search_placeholder="Search for a service" all_items_labels="All Tags, All Location"]
```

For me, I replaced All Tags with All location. Somehow label change only works for the **second** item of the shortcode. In my case Its `product_cat`.

Try to play around with the shortcode/label with this code.

Answer (score 0):

I fix it with this:

```
[searchandfilter fields="search,category,post_tag" submit_label ="Search" search_placeholder="any keyword" all_items_labels=",All Technologies, All Countries" headings="Search,Technologies,Countries"]
```